# Binding data model with FormBuilder in Angular 2

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have a form which I use to edit data.

When I open my form, I get the `Title` value in my input.

But `{{ uForm.value | json }}` shows it empty, if I type a char in to the input, the uForm.value gets updated

```
{{ uForm.value | json }}
<form [formGroup]="uForm" (submit)="saveItem()">
    <div class="group">
        <div class="field">
            <label>Title</label>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
            <input formControlName="Title" type="text" class="full" name="Title" value="{{userData.Title}}">
        </div>
    </div>
</form>



uForm: any;

constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.uForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'Title': ['', Validators.required],
    });
```

**What i tried**

```
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.uForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        'Title': [this.userData.Title, Validators.required], // Cannot read property 'Title' of undefined
    });
```

How do I bind the values `userData` to  uForm? Because now if I want to update a value, the others are empty

Comment: have you tried the same with `[(ngModel)]`?